Requirements for a mile-high hot air balloon flight
I want my world to have balloons that can fly at least 6,000 feet high. However, I’m not sure that my world’s level of technology would be able to make such a thing feasible. So, what materials, construction techniques, and technologies would be needed to make a hot air balloon that can fly at such high altitudes?
Specifications

Must be able to sustain an altitude of 6,000 ft for one hour or longer
Must be able to carry the weight of one person and some surveying/astronomy equipment (200 lbs or so total)
No magic

For this question, don’t worry about the survival of the passengers. Furthermore, if possible, I would like for the answer to include the approximate point in our history where we could theoretically build a hot air balloon that could fly to 6,000 feet or higher

IIRC Montgolfier balloon could reach that high, probably not right away. And essentially you just need an onboard hot air source that doesn't ruin the balloon; just light a bonfire out of the payload with an iron net in the chimney to not let sparks inside, and that's pretty much all.

My first reading of the subject was a request for a balloon envelope that had height of one mile. That is a balloon itself being over mile tall.

Vijaypat Singhania holds the world record for highest flight by a hot air balloon. It was 21km (~69000 feet). It is eleven times more than what you need.
More information about the balloon he used can be found here.
Lifted from comment:
Apparently first hot air balloon flight exceeding the requirements happened already in 1784 by Jean-François Pilâtre de Rozier. He reached 3km (~9800 feet).

Sure, but when did the first balloon exceed 2000 meters above ground level?

@JonCusterIf I got it right (ie. the balloon was really a hot air balloon), it was in 1784 by Jean-François Pilâtre de Rozier. He reached 3km (~9800 feet). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean-Fran%C3%A7ois_Pil%C3%A2tre_de_Rozier

You should edit that in to your answer! Nice find.
